# How can we show whether this is a metric or not?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Define a function $d(x,y)=\arctan|x-y|$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Is this a metric on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a metric?

Comment: Hint: in considering the triangle inequality, take $|x-y||y-z|>1$. That's the easier case.

Comment: Or better, $|x-y|>1$ and $|y-z|>1$.

Answer (score 4):

The three conditions that must be satisfied by any metric are:

$$d(x, y) \geq 0,\; \text{ and }\,d(x, y) = 0 \iff x = y$$
$$d(x, y) = d(y, x)$$
$$d(x, y) + d(y, z) \geq  d(x, z), \quad \forall x, y, z \in \mathbb R$$

Your task is to show whether (or not) $d(x, y) = \arctan|x - y|$ satisfies each and every property above.

---

Added:

Is $\arctan|x - y|$ always non-negative? If yes, we can continue.

And if yes, is it possible that $\arctan|x - y| = 0$, but $x\neq y$? (If no, we can continue. If yes, the function is not a metric.

Symmetry is quite obvious: $\arctan|x - y| = \arctan|y - x|$, by virtue of the absolute value sign.

If all is good, so far, your final task is to determine whether $\arctan|x - y| + \arctan|y - z| \geq \arctan |x - z|$ for all $x, y, z \in \mathbb R$. If not, then the function fails to be a metric.

Comment: I know this properties but I cannot show it in this function

Comment: See my edit above: I'm added a bit more regarding this particular function.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Silly me! Thanks for pointing that out so I could correct my careless typo!

Answer (score 0):

Answer the following questions:

1. Is it non-negative for all $(x,y)$?
2. Is it zero if and only if $x = y$?
3. Is it symmetric, i.e. $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$?
4. Does it satisfy the triangle inequality, $d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y,z)$?

Questions 1 to 3 are quite easy to answer. Question 4 requires some basic algebra to answer.

Comment: I know this properties but I cannot show it in this function

Comment: @1214 Which of these properties are you having trouble showing?

Comment: specially 4.property

Comment: @Arkamis Prop 1 can be derived from 2 to 4

Comment: @Matthew Of course it can, but being that it is a simple test, there is no reason not to include it as the first, and easiest, element to check off a list.

Comment: @Arkamis I see your point.

Comment: so,it is a metric?

Answer (score 0):

Any function $d$ is  a metric if it satisfies the follow properties for all $x,y,z \in \Bbb R$:

1. $d(x,y)=0 $ $\iff x=y$
2. $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$
3. $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z) + d(z,y) \quad \forall  x,y,z \in \Bbb R$

Comment: I know this properties but I cannot show it in this function

Comment: I would like a explanation

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I think it was because 1. is actually "if and only if".

Comment: @alex I guess that is appropriate

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide whether
$$
\arctan|a+b| \leq \arctan|a| + \arctan|b|
$$
Always holds.  It is possible to show that this is indeed the case using (only) the fact that $\arctan(x)$ is a concave function on $[0,\infty)$.